# cannot insert data into vue select sent from laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-select

This is the vuejs component for editing song info. the problem here is with tags.I cannot show the tags of the song in vue select for editing.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <a data-toggle="modal" :data-target="'#EditModal'+ modalid" @click="select(song)"><span title="edit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></span></a>
        <a class=""><span title="delete" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>

        <!-- Modal for editing song tracks-->
        <div class="modal fade" :id="'EditModal'+ modalid" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="EditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="EditModalLabel">Edit Song</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" ref="closemodal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form ref="uploadform">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <button type="button" @click="browseImage" class="btn btn-md btn-default">Choose image:</button>
                                            <div id="image_previews">
                                                <img ref='image' class="" v-bind:src="image" width="200px" height="200px" >
                                                <input class="form-control-file" ref="imageinput" type="file" name="feature_image" @change="showImage($event)">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="title">Song Title:</label>
                                                <input type="text" v-model="esong.title" class="form-control" required maxlength="255">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="genre"> Genre (tag atleast one) </label>
                                                <v-select :placeholder="'choose tag'" v-model="tagids" label="name" multiple :options="tags"></v-select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="upload_type">Song Upload Type</label>
                                                <select name="upload_type" v-model="esong.upload_type" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="public">public( free )</option>
                                                    <option value="private">private( for sale )</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Description:</label>
                                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" v-model="esong.song_description"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group" v-if="private">
                                                <label for="upload_type">Song price</label>
                                                <input type="text" v-model="esong.amount" class="form-control" required maxlength="255">

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="edit">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of modal -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import vSelect from 'vue-select'

    export default {

        props: ['song','modalid','index','tags'],

        components: {vSelect},
        
        mounted() {

        },

        watch: {
            tagids() {
                console.log('changed tagids value');
               // this.value = this.tagsid;
            }
        },

        computed: {
            private() {
                if(this.esong.upload_type == 'private') {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },

        },

        methods: {
            
            select(song) {
                console.log(song.title);
                this.getTagIds(song);   
            },

            edit() {
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('title', this.esong.title);
                formData.append('img', this.esong.img);
                formData.append('description', this.esong.song_description);
                formData.append('upload_type', this.esong.upload_type);
                formData.append('amount', this.esong.amount);
                formData.append('tags', JSON.stringify(this.tagids));
                formData.append('_method', 'PUT');

                axios.post('/artist/songs/' + this.esong.id, formData,{
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }).then(response =>{
                    this.$refs.closemodal.click();
                    toastr.success('successfully edited song.');
                    this.$emit('update', {song:this.esong,index:this.index});
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            },

            getTagIds(song) {

                axios.post('/gettagids', song ).then(response =>{
                    this.tagids  = response.data;

                }).catch(error =>{
                    console.log(error);
                });

            },

            browseImage() {
                this.$refs.imageinput.click();
            },

            showImage(event) {
                this.esong.img = event.target.files[0];
                this.image = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            }

        },

        data() {
                
            return {

                esong: this.song,
                tagids: {id:'', name:'', label:''},
                name:'name',
                image:this.song.image
            }
        }
    }

</script>
<style scoped>

input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

#image_previews {
    border-radius: 5px;background-color: whitesmoke; width: 200px; height: 200px;
}

.btn{
    border-radius: 0px;
}

</style>
```

here I cannot get the selected value that was inserted in my table. I wanted to show the tagged values for a song. I am able to get all object of tagged songs from axios post request but v-select doesn't shows the selected value retrieved from a table.
the object received from laravel is similar to the object provided in options which work well with v-select..but it doesn't show the same structure object provided to v-model..or should I provide other props. the document for vue select has not mentioned any of these things

Comment: So it shows correct options (`tags`), but it doesn't select the ones that the song already has selected?

Comment: Share live code ? All code related to this ?

Comment: @devk yes that is exactly the problem